# How to use the Beaglebone Black's PRUs?

Tags: beagleboneblack

I would like to use the PRUs of my Beaglebone Black. I 've been following several tuturials from the internet whithout any significant success. Most documents are outdated because the bone_capemgr is no longer supported (at least from what I understood). So how can I use the PRUs in combination with one of the Linux systems provided by beaglebone.org?

Answer (score 0):

A programmable real-time unit (**PRU**) is a fast (200-MHz, 32-bit) processor with single-cycle I/O access to a number of pins and full access to the internal memory and peripherals of the BeagleBone (http://beagleboard.org/pru).

There are many tutorials online for **PRU** coding on newer beaglebone images.

I would suggest you to get familiar with the [PRU Libraries](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/PRU-ICSS_Remoteproc_and_RPMsg) and then try some simple and recent [blink code](https://github.com/shirriff/pru-blink) or follow some example of [remoteproc](https://elinux.org/EBC_Exercise_30_PRU_via_remoteproc_and_RPMsg) usage.